# How do you determine which process is using up Linux aio context capacity?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, aio

In Linux, you can read the value of `/proc/sys/fs/aio-nr` and this returns the total no. of events allocated across all active aio contexts in the system. The max value is controlled by `/proc/sys/fs/aio-max-nr`.

Is there a way to tell which process is responsible for allocating these aio contexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a simple way.  At least, not that I've ever found!  However, you can see them being consumed and freed using `systemtap`.

https://blog.pythian.com/troubleshooting-ora-27090-async-io-errors/

Attempting to execute the complete script in that article produced errors on my Centos 7 system.  But, if you just take the first part of it, the part that logs allocations, it may give you enough insight:

```
stap -ve '
global allocated, allocatedctx

probe syscall.io_setup {
  allocatedctx[pid()] += maxevents; allocated[pid()]++;
  printf("%d AIO events requested by PID %d (%s)\n",
    maxevents, pid(), cmdline_str());
}
'
```

You'll need to coordinate things such that systemtap is running *before* your workload kicks in.

Install systemtap, then execute the above command.  (Note, I've altered this slightly from the linked article to removed the unused `freed` symbol.)  After a few seconds, it'll be running.  Then, start your workload.

```
Pass 1: parsed user script and 469 library scripts using 227564virt/43820res/6460shr/37524data kb, in 260usr/10sys/263real ms.
Pass 2: analyzed script: 5 probes, 14 functions, 101 embeds, 4 globals using 232632virt/51468res/11140shr/40492data kb, in 80usr/150sys/240real ms.
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install kernel-lt-4.4.70-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
Pass 3: using cached /root/.systemtap/cache/55/stap_5528efa47c2ab60ad2da410ce58a86fc_66261.c
Pass 4: using cached /root/.systemtap/cache/55/stap_5528efa47c2ab60ad2da410ce58a86fc_66261.ko
Pass 5: starting run.
```

Then, once your workload starts, you'll see the context requests logged:

```
128 AIO events requested by PID 28716 (/Users/blah/awesomeprog)
128 AIO events requested by PID 28716 (/Users/blah/awesomeprog)
```

So, not as simple as `lsof`, but I think it's all we have!

Comment: Very cool - that worked! It turns out I was running into a Linux kernel bug that did not count aio-nr correctly. They fixed it in 4.16 kernel it looks like. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/2a8a98673c13cb2a61a6476153acf8344adfa992

Comment: Wow... thanks for posting about that bug!  Glad the systemtap thing worked for you!